# Why I have problem with $(document).ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I'm learning jQuery but I have a problem.

Here the code:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js';
script.type = "text/javascript";

var pt = document.createElement('script');
pt.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(pt);

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("ti vedo");
  $.post('wait.php', function(data) {
    alert("ti vedo2");
    var dati = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data);
    for (var i = 0; i <= dati.length; i++) {
      var node = $(document.createElement("span"));
      var content = $(document.createElement("div"));
      var code = dati[i];
      var text = $(document.createTextNode(code));
      node.append(text);
      content.append(node);
      $("#boxMessage").append(content);
    }
  });
});
```

I use alert to check the error, but I can't see the first alert. So the problem is $(document)... but I don't understand why. I'm making a mistake when I include the jQuery library? Thank you for the Help!

Comment: Do you not have access to the html to include the script there?

Comment: Why are you trying to load 2 versions of jQuery? Also couldn't you just load it in the html?

Comment: Your jQuery isn't getting loaded prior to your invocation of `$`, which is... a reference to jQuery! What's keeping you from loading jQuery with a script tag in your HTML rather than this awkward programmatic way?

Comment: I can see if you are loading the same version from two different CDNs, but one is one minor version higher...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're trying to access `jQuery` (via `$`) before it's available.

You can run your jQuery-related code after the script was really loaded:

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js';
script.type="text/javascript";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  
script.addEventListener('load', function(){
  alert("ti vedo");
  $.post('wait.php',function(data){
    alert("ti vedo2");
    var dati=JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data);
    for(var i=0; i<=dati.length; i++){
      var node=$(document.createElement("span"));
        var content=$(document.createElement("div"));
        var code=dati[i];
        var text=$(document.createTextNode(code));
        node.append(text);
        content.append(node);
        $("#boxMessage").append(content);
    }
  });
});
```

Also, you don't need two different versions of `jQuery` simultaneously.

Comment: You could also listen to `DOMContentLoaded` and use `fetch` API and drop jQuery altogether. ES5/6 can do a majority of what jQuery does without all the extra baggage.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl for sure!

Answer (score 0):

The order of activities is:

1. A script element to load jQuery 3.4.1 is added to the DOM
2. A script element to load jQuery 3.5.1 is added to the DOM
3. The `$` function is called, but `$` is undefined, so the script terminates with an exception
4. jQuery 3.4.1 is loaded, adding `$` to the environment
5. jQuery 3.5.1 is loaded, overwriting `$`

Use a regular `<script>` element to load your dependencies instead of trying to load them half way through executing your script.